# Delete photos via the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

Is it possible to delete photos via the Foursquare API?  I don't see any mention of it at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/, nor did a wild guess of /v2/photos/delete/**photoID** do anything.

I also didn't see any way to do this (or even see my photos) via the web.  It would be nice if there was a way to do this so as to avoid cluttering venues + checkins with photos while in development/testing.  Hoping I just missed it.

Thanks!

--Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it on the web at the moment, but you can definitely delete photos from the mobile client (long-press on Android, swipe left on iOS).

The delete photo API endpoint is not publicly available because we haven't built the ability to "undo" deletes yet and don't want apps accidentally (and permantently) deleting a user's photos.

Comment: Thanks Akshay! Maybe a good middle ground would be to allow an app to delete only photos that were uploaded by that app?

Comment: Good suggestion. We'll think about it!